# XSL Output Text

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:for-each select="$all_events[g:active = true()][g:body/g:current = true()]">
        <xsl:for-each select="g:body">
            <h2 class="normal"><xsl:value-of select="g:sub_title" /></h2>
                <xsl:for-each select="g:paragraphs">
                    <xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="g:paragraph" /></xsl:text>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:for-each>
```

Here is my XSL, take notice to the following line:

```
<xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="g:paragraph" /></xsl:text>
```

I tried this because the `g:paragraph` is coming from a WYSIWYG and it was printing out the `<p> </p>` tags and whatever else. This process of encapsulating it within `xsl:text` tags caused an error. What is the proper way to either hide the tags (because I want the styles to still be applied if included (i.e. bold, underlined)?

Edit:

The output currently is `<p>whatever</p>`

I want it to be `whatever`

Comment: You're missing a lot of detail here required to understand your question. First of all, the only thing that can be within an `xsl:text` element is text. Second of all, it seems like you're asking about how to remove XML tags that are within `g:paragraph`. Is that right? Can you give an example of the input file, the output you have now and the output you want to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out. I just had to use `disable-output-escaping="yes"`

Comment: So `g:paragraph` just contains text, not an HTML node? `disable-output-escaping` is still outputting a `<p>` tag, then. You're not actually removing it.

Comment: It is but it's not printing it out as text. Regardless it works.

Answer (score 0):

You want to select the text content from a `p` element inside the `g:paragraph` element. You can do that this way:

```
<xsl:for-each select="g:paragraphs">
  <xsl:value-of select="g:paragraph/p" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: What about if there are other HTML tags?